# Regex js to match that a string contains 0 or 1 repeated characters

Tags: javascript

## I have a string that contains 4 digits. I need to check whether this string has no more than 1 repeated digit.

**This group should be matched:**

> ```
> 1234  match    // no repeated digits
> 1123  match    // only one repeated digit 1
> 1213  match
> 1231  match
> 1223  match
> 1233  match
> ```

**This group should not be matched:**

```
1222  fail   //digit 2 repeated 3 times
2222  fail
1112  fail
1211  fail
1212  fail   // digits 1 and 2 repeated 2 times
1122  fail
1221  fail
```

**I tried these 2 regex, but they don't work correctly**

- > ^(?:(\d)(?!(.).*\2)){4}$
- > ^(?:(\d)(?!.*\1{2}))(?:(\d)(?!.\2)){3}$

**Here are my links:**

- https://regex101.com/r/34FExf/1
- https://regex101.com/r/vTIdAD/1

Comment: .... and what part of your code is not working ?

Comment: Add them to your question (not as a comment)

Comment: you should give a plain english description of what inputs are valid and which are not.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I agree! All I have understood is that he want to check if there is separated `1` or `0` in the string. But it's still vague.

Comment: Do you want to macth all 4-characters-long strings that are made up of at least 3 distinctive characters.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir Yes

Comment: You cannot solve this problem using regex because the rule you want to apply can only be described by a context-free grammar (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).
What you need is a PDA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)

Comment: @torazaburo I need only one digit to be repeated. 1212 - two digits repeated

Answer (score 1):

This problem isn't a good fit for regular expressions with your provided input as the input doesn't follow a regular pattern (also, any length changes in your string would be difficult to deal with). Instead, I would advise simply iterating over the string and noting any duplicates.

Here is one method of doing this:

```js
function almostUnique(input) {
    var hasDuplicate = false;
    var cache = new Set();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (cache.has(input[i])) {
            if (hasDuplicate) {
                return false; // We already have a duplicate, so this is the second duplicate
            }
            hasDuplicate = true;
        } else {
            cache.add(input[i])
        }
    }
    return true; // Only one duplicate, or no duplicates.
}

console.log('1234 match', almostUnique('1234'));
console.log('1123 match', almostUnique('1123'));
console.log('1213 match', almostUnique('1213'));
console.log('1231 match', almostUnique('1231'));
console.log('1223 match', almostUnique('1223'));
console.log('1233 match', almostUnique('1233'));

console.log('1222 fail', almostUnique('1222'));
console.log('2222 fail', almostUnique('2222'));
console.log('1112 fail', almostUnique('1112'));
console.log('1211 fail', almostUnique('1211'));
console.log('1212 fail', almostUnique('1212'));
console.log('1122 fail', almostUnique('1122'));
console.log('1221 fail', almostUnique('1221'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with regexp. This regexp matches if the rule is broken.

```js
const re = /(.).*\1.*\1|(.).*\2.*(.).*\3|(.).*(.).*\4.*\5|(.).*(.).*\7.*\6/;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^                                                     a..a..a
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    a..a..b..b
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   a..b..a..b
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  a..b..b..a

const data = [1234, 1123, 1213, 1231, 1223, 1233, 1222, 2222, 1112, 1211, 1212, 1122, 1221];

data.forEach(x => console.log(x, re.test(x) ? "fail" : "pass"));
```

If you are willing to sort the string beforehand, then the regexp is just

```
/(.)\1\1|(.)\2.*(.)\3/
```

Comment: +1 because I'm impressed that this works, though I would hate anyone who wrote that in anything I have to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings were only 4 characters long then this test will be equivalent to testing if there is at least 3 distinctive characters in the string. So this function will work:

```
function test(str){
    var chars = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if(chars.indexOf(str[i]) == -1)
            chars.push(str[i]);

    return chars.length >= 3;
}
```

**TESTS:**

```
test("1123"); // true
test("1234"); // true
test("1211"); // false
test("1122"); // false
```